Strange error when user attempts document upload
One of my SharePoint 2019 site's users can no longer upload documents to a specific library. When they attempt to do so, a red X appears over the refresh symbol next to the All Documents dropdown on the right. The error is confusing since I don't even see the refresh symbol when I view the library.


As a workaround, the user switched to classic view. The alert may be because they are replacing an existing file.
